# How to import and call a library project from an Eclipse ADT application project?

Tags: android, eclipse

I built an android project in **eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32-x86_64**. From here on this project is referred to as ***Libexample***. It is a simple "hello world" project. I run it. I got the expected result on the android virtual device.

Now, I have made ***Libexample*** a library project by checking the '*Is Library*' field in its properties. I built another project, from here on referred to as ***Appexample***. I would like to call the library project ***Libexample*** from ***Appexample***. As a first step, I have added ***Libexample*** as a reference to ***Appexample*** in the properties for ***Appexample***. But, I am not finding a way by which I can import and call ***Libexample*** from ***Appexample***.

Running ***Appexample*** (in which there is a call to ***Libexample***) should yield the same result as I got by running ***Libexample***.

Can anyone give Me an idea to make this work the way I want it to ??

Comment: Read [Managing Projects from Eclipse with ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html).

Answer (score 2):

to add a library, you go in the properties of the project, under the tab 'android', in the library section, add the library and make sure there is a green tick next to it.

secondly, beware. importing a library does not import anything in the project manifest. you have to add elements to the manifest yourself if you need, like, activities or services from the library

Comment: Also beware they use same folder hieracky or it will blow.

Comment: Yes. True. In the '_manifest_.xml' of **Libexample**, I have declared the Activity _AppexampleActivity_. Also, In the '_manifest_.xml' of the **Appexample**, I have declared the library Activity _LibexampleActivity_ in the format specified in the following link "developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html". I have also written an import statement in **Appexample**. But where am I actually entering into the library **Libexample**?